# disadvantages of inheritance in java

Tags: java, inheritance

Can anyone explain disadvantage of inheritance in java

Comment: not java perse,if somebody explains the cons of inheritance..that's a good read.:)

Comment: Can you...contain the scope of your question a bit? Are there specific issues you're worried about? For instance, single- vs. multiple-inheritance, or class vs. prototypical inheritance, or... (Or is this homework?)

Comment: disadvantage compared to inheritance in other languages, or disadvantages of inheritance compared to composition for example?

Comment: See also [Fragile base class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragile_base_class).

Answer (score 9):

you probably want to read:

Effective Java™, Second Edition
By: Joshua Bloch

Chapter 4. Classes and Interfaces

Item 16: Favor composition over inheritance

Item 17: Design and document for inheritance or else prohibit it

Item 18: Prefer interfaces to abstract classes

Answer (score 5):

Take a loot at Allen Holub's article in JavaWorld entitled [Why extends is evil](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-08-2003/jw-0801-toolbox.html).  He discusses things like tight-coupling and the [fragile base class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragile_base_class) problem.

Comment: The article does not shun inheritance per se, only extending concrete base classes.

Answer (score 3):

Unless your class is designed for inheritance, it should be made final.  You have to be very careful to make sure you understand how methods which will be overridden in a sub class which was not designed for inheritance function, so as to understand how to modify them.

**A specific example:**

Consider you have a class that manages a list of names...

```
public class MyNameManager {
  private List<String> numbers = new LinkedList<String>();

  public void add(String value) {
    numbers.add(value);
  }

  public void addAll(Collection<String> values) {
    for(String value : values) {
      add(value);
    }
  }

  public void remove(String value) { //... }

  //...
}
```

Now say you want to create a new subclass which also counts the total number of times a name gets added to the list, like so:

```
public class MyCountingNameManager extends MyNameManager {
  private int count = 0;

  @Override
  protected void addAll(Collection<String> values) {
    count += values.size();
    super.addAll(values);
  }

  @Override
  protected void add(String value) {
    count += 1;
    super.add(value);
  }
}
```

Seems pretty straightforward, no?  But consider the result of the following:

```
MyCountingNameManager m = new MyCountingNameManager();
m.add("bob");
m.add("Sally");
```

The count is now 2, and all is well.  But if we were to do the following:

```
List<String> family = new List<String>();
family.add("mom");
family.add("dad");
family.add("brother");

MyCountingNameManager m = new MyCountingNameManager();
m.add(family);
```

The count is now 6, **not** the 3 you'd probably expect.  This is because the call to `addAll` adds the size of the Collection of values (which is 3) to the count, and then calls the `super.addAll` method to do the actual processing.  `super.addAll` iterates the Collection and calls the `add` method for each value.  But since we're working in an `MyCountingNameManager` and **not** a `MyNameManager`, the overridden `add` method in the sub class is called each time.  The `MyCountingNameManager.add` method which gets executed also increments the count!  So the result is each name gets counted twice!

I believe this example comes from Effective Java.  You should definitely find a copy and read the items listed in Viele's answer for a deeper understanding of some cases where inheritance is a bad fit.

Answer (score 2):

We prefer composition over inheritance because when we add (particularly) or change functionality by subclassing, we couple that new functionality to the class - so anywhere we need the new functionality, we need that class.  That extends even to further subclasses - and with Java's single-inheritance model, if we have two new bits of functionality we want in yet another class, there's no (simple) way to bring both bits in, if each is in a separate subclass of the original ancestor.

By comparison, if we extend functionality via composition, any class - in or out of our existing hierarchy - can incorporate it by simply including the tiny class that has the new function.  It's simpler, cleaner, more reusable, and easier to read.

Inheritance has its place, but it's not the right tool for many, many jobs.

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance gives tightly coupled relationship between classes and is heavy weight compared to interfaces for runtime polymorphism.